# Chakra UI: Card element from Chakra throws 31 errors. in React

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

My code seems fine but it keeps throwing errors. All other elements in Chakra-UI work.

My code:

https://pastebin.com/RghmXJm1
`The code`

[Image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoCDG.jpg)

https://pastebin.com/KejLfA1L
`The errors`

I tried creating a new React project with only the Chakra module and it still didn't work but only gave the errors in the console and it showed a white page.

https://pastebin.com/ks91pA55`The errors on chrome console`

In all of the cases, the code compiles perfectly with no errors but upon the visiting of the oage it all breaks down.

Comment: Somewhat fixed now, I was on an outdated version of chakra and react but now after the upgrade, i get a new error

Comment: Please include your relevant code in a minimal reproducible example within the question. Don't link to external sites for it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somewhat fixed now, I was on an outdated version of chakra and react but now after the upgrade, i get a new error.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (103:18)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   const [hasBody, setHasBody] = useState(false);
|   const uuid = useId();
>   const uid = id ?? uuid;
|   const [triggerId, popoverId, headerId, bodyId] = ["popover-trigger", "popover-content", "popover-header", "popover-body"].map(id2 => `${id2}-${uid}`);
|   const {
```

[See here for new SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553078/chakra-ui-module-parse-failed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).